# How to fix broken VS2010 setup project after installing VS 11 Beta

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, visual-studio-2012

After installing VS 11 beta, I've found that my setup project in VS 2010 builds, but fails to install correctly on Windows Server 2003. I have a Custom Installer Action in the project, and using WiLogUtl.exe shows that it's failing on this step.

I've installed VS2010 on another machine and can now build my setup project successfully again, but I'd like to get my main development machine back up and working.

I've tried using the Repair function in the VS2010 installer but it hasn't had any effect.

I'm not sure exactly what is going wrong with the install iteself - WiLogUtl.exe doesn't really give any clues except that it's failing (return code 3) in the customer installer action step.

Comment: Try posting a verbose installation log so we can investigate it: http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log. Verbose logs contain a lot more information than WiLogUtl.exe shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the introduction of .NET 4.5 rather then VS11 per say that is causing the problem.  Do you see any 1001 error codes in the log file before the return code of 3?

FWIW,  InstallUtil (InstallerClass) custom actions are notoriously brittle and VS Setup Projects have been deprecated from VS11.

You should consider porting to InstallShield Limited Edition ( Free to VS customers and Microsofts roadmap item to replace Setup Projects ) and refactor your InstallUtil CA's to use the Windows Installer XML's (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).

Comment: The problem was indeed .NET 4.5 - I uninstalled it, and that broke VS2010 completely - "Unknown Error" message box just trying to open VS! But I did a repair/reinstall and now I'm back being able to build the setup project correctly. I'll certainly be looking to migrate to WiX in the future, but for now it's got me out of a hole! Thanks :)

Comment: FWIW, you might want to look into the use of VM's for your builds. It's really nice to be able to create a snapshot and roll back to it.